# c++ SIGTERM not returning after caught

Tags: c++, linux, unix

I am trying to catch SIGTERM in my program, this is the problem.

My program starts and sets ups the listener for the signal SIGTERM. The program then enters a loop which continuously checks a socket file descriptor using select so that it is non blocking.When I send the program TERM through kill the program acknowledges that it receives the signal but that's it no return back to the loop I describe earlier.

The signal handler sets a public variable inside the class so the loop knows to exit. I should mention that in gdb this works but outside of gdb it does not.

Thanks in advance.

```
class A
{
    public:
        bool volatile stop;

    void loop();
    {
        while(!stop)
            {
                //check socket
            }
    }
};

A *aptr;

void sigterm_handler(int i)
{
    aptr->stop = true;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    aptr = &a;
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = &sigterm_handler;
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &sa, NULL);
    a.stop = false;
    a.loop();
}
```

EDIT: sorry did not finish the code off properly.

Comment: There is a problem with the code you posted: `stop` is not initialized, and `loop()` is not called.

Comment: You probably want to make stop volatile.

Comment: What platform are you using and what compiler flags?  Asking because this worked for me with a simple `g++ -o test test.cpp` (where you file is test.cpp), but if I added an optimization flag like `g++ -O2 -o test test.cpp`, then you will need to take @linuts answer which is to make `stop` volatile in order for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make stop "volatile" otherwise the compiler won't actually check it in the loop as it thinks it can't change.

```
bool volatile stop;
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is related with the other members of `struct sigaction` that are not initialized. `gdb` maybe initializes the memory to 0, whereas it is not initiazlized without `gdb`.

Answer (score 0):

You might find that *any* signal (especially SIGTERM) will terminate any system calls you are doing inside the while loop. And by "system calls" I mean anything that reads from or does select or connect on a socket.

[Check out this write up.](http://www.madore.org/~david/computers/connect-intr.html)

[Also check the example test program](https://bugs.python.org/file38411/connect_test.c).

Comment: @Pang LMGTFY. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned above volatile is the correct answer. Also I'd like to add that according to you code sigwait() will be better solution instead the loop... BTW in case of sigwait you do not need signal handler

Opps, sorry miss a socket operations